# PointCut not triggered in Spring Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-aop, applicationcontext

I define an Aspect and its config in the application-context.xml like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<bean id="myAspect" class="myAspectClass"/>
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="myAspect">
      <aop:pointcut id="myPointCut" expression="(@within(MyPointCutAnnotation) or @annotation(MyPointCutAnnotation)) and execution(* *(..))"/>
      <aop:before pointcut-ref="myPointCut" method="beforeMethod" />   
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

And my servlet-context.xml looks something like this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />
```

My Spring Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( value="/xxx", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public class MyController {  
    @MyPointCutAnnotation    
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping( value="/signOn" )
    public void myMethod() {
        ...do something
    }  
}
```

The web.xml is as following:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

But myPointCut doesn't get triggered for myMethod, unless I add the following (importing root context) in servlet-context.xml like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:application-context.xml"/ >
```

Could someone tell me why this is happening? Aren't all beans including Aspect, PointCut and Advice automatically made available in Controller by Spring through context hierarchy?

Comment: Are you using maven? if yes, can you share your pom.xml's build tag part? May be you need to add aspectj builder your pom.xml.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven, here is my build tag part: `<build>
  <plugins>
   <!-- Use Java 1.6 instead of the default 1.5 as source/target for the 
    javac compiler -->
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>${javase.version}</source>
     <target>${javase.version}</target>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>`

Comment: I'm not familiar with aspectj builder. What is it for and how can it help solve the problem?

Comment: was this probelm solved? I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your pom. May be your problem can solve.

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```